# Laravel Upgrade to PHP 8.1: Attribute value must be of type bool for selected attribute, array given: Laravel Upgrade to PHP 8.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

When upgrading to PHP8.1 from PHP8.0 I receive the following error:

`Attribute value must be of type bool for selected attribute, array given`

This only seems to happen when doing Eloquent queries. E.g. when running this code from routes/web.php:

`Route::get('/test', function() { return "hi"; });`

It works. When running

`Route::get('/test', function() { return \App\Page::all(); });`

The error is given. Does anybody have an idea what could cause it?

Comment: Does it happen for all models?

Comment: Do you have any particular casts/accessors in that model that have been defined?

Comment: It happens for all models indeed.

Comment: I also tried this by creating a new empty model with php artisan make:model TestModel

`Route::get('/test', function()
{ return \App\TestModel::all(); });`

Even then, the Error is given.

Comment: What do you expect to be returned from this route? Usually, a response should contain a string, not an array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that in the config/database.php there were wrong settings in the mysql driver:

```
'options' => [\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true + extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
```

When changing this to:

```
'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
```

It gets resolved